# my function called in data.table j not returning expected results

Tags: r, data.table

The indexing problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238521/selected-rows-in-data-table-not-being-removed-first-time-must-remove-twice) is resolved with the devel `data.table` version 1.9.7.

My question is about understanding what I've done wrong in sending data to and returning from my own function.

As described in the other question I want to keep only the longest continuous segment for each `gvkey` and if there are multiple equal length segments, take the most recent.

```
 DT[, fyear.lag := shift(fyear, n=1L, type = "lag"), by = gvkey]
 DT[, gap := fyear - fyear.lag]
```

Here I get the expected results (with `data.table` v1.9.7):

```
DT[,         step.idx := 0]    # initialize
DT[gap >=2 , step.idx := 1]    # 1's at each multi-year jump
DT[, step.idx := cumsum(step.idx), by = gvkey] # indexes each sequence by firm
DT[ ,  seq.lengths := .N,  by=.(gvkey,step.idx)]      # length of each sequence
DT[,   keep.seq := 1*(seq.lengths == max(seq.lengths)), by = gvkey]        # each firm's longest sequence
DT[keep.seq==1,  keep.seq := c(rep(0, (.N-max(seq.lengths))), rep(1, max(seq.lengths))), by = gvkey] 

 #' expected results:
 DT.out <- DT[keep.seq==1] # 23
 DT.out[keep.seq==0, .N] # 0 
 nrow(DT.out)#   [1] 149
```

When I try essentially the same process with my own function I get extra `keep.seq==0` cases. **My question is why don't I get the same result as above** from this:

```
find.seq.keep <- function(g){
    step.idx = rep(0, length(g))
    step.idx[g>=2] = 1
    step.idx = cumsum(step.idx)
    N.seq = length(unique(step.idx))

    seq.lengths = as.vector(unlist(tapply(step.idx, step.idx,
                     function(x) rep(length(x), length(x)))))
    keep.seq = 1*(seq.lengths == max(seq.lengths))
    if(length(keep.seq[keep.seq == 1]) > max(seq.lengths)){
      N.max = max(seq.lengths)
      N.1s  = length(keep.seq[keep.seq==1])
      keep.seq[keep.seq==1] = c(rep(0, (N.1s-N.max)), rep(1, N.max))
    }
return(as.list(keep.seq))
}
DT[,keep.seqF := find.seq.keep(gap), by = gvkey]
```

Removal of the rows works but there are some false positives of what to remove:

```
   DT.outF <- DT[keep.seqF==1]
   DT.outF[keep.seqF==0, .N]  # 0
   nrow(DT.outF)   # 141 (<149 = nrow(DT.out)  !!)
```

<s>I would like to make my personal function work so that I could still use version 1.9.6 (making it easier to share with colleagues), at least until 1.9.7 is on CRAN.</s>  Now that Frank has provided a solution to my issue, I would like to get a better grip of what's going on with the `j` argument when I call `find.seq.keep`.

=======

** Reproducible Example Data ***

```
DT <- data.table(
   gvkey =  c(1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 1681, 
              1681, 1681, 1681, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 
              1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 1914, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
              2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
              2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
              2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
              2011, 2011, 2011, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 
              2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 
              2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 
              2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085,
              2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2085, 2164, 2164, 2164, 2164, 
              2164, 2164, 2164, 2164, 2164, 2164, 2164, 2164, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 
              2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 2185, 
              2185, 2185, 2185),
   fyear = c(1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1997, 1998, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
             2012, 2013, 2014, 1983, 1984, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
             2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965,
             1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 
             1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991,
             1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2007, 2008, 
             2009, 2010, 2011, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 
             1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973,
             1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
             1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
             2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 
             1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974,
             1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
             1988, 1994, 1995))

setkey(DT, gvkey, fyear)
```

Comment: Could you please shorten the post by narrowing the issue?I

Comment: I've shortened it.

Comment: Your Q now is about debugging a function you wrote in base R, IIUC. And it's most likely at the place you're creating `seq.lengths`, where you use `gvkey,step.idx` groups, and just `step.idx` in tapply. Use `debugonce()` on your function, then rerun it line by line while checking the output.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the `debugonce()` function -- I didn't know of it, and it's quite helpful.  I tried running through my function in debug mode and I *did* receive the expected result for the first `gvkey==1681` case (namely an index of 9 0's followed by 7 1's).  However, when I call this same function in `j` in `data.table` it returns a list of all zeros (length 16).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why your function is not working, but here's an alternative approach:

```
DT[, g := cumsum( fyear - shift(fyear, fill=fyear[1L]-1L) != 1L ), by=gvkey]
keep = DT[, 
  .(len = .N), by=.(gvkey, g)][, 
  .( g = g[tail(which(len == max(len)), 1)]), by=gvkey]

DT.out = DT[keep, on=names(keep)]

DT.out[, .N] # 149, as expected
```

*How it works:*

- `g` is an ID for runs within each `gvkey`.
- `len` is the length of each run.
- `g[tail(which(len == max(len)), 1)]` is the longest, breaking ties by taking the most recent.
- `DT[keep, on=names(keep)` is a merge that subsets `DT` to the `(gvkey,g)` found in keep.

---

If, for some reason, you wanted a base function to do this...

```
tag.long.seq = function(x){
    g    = cumsum(c(1L, diff(x) > 1L))
    len  = tapply(g, g, FUN = length)
    w    = tail(which(len == max(len)), 1L)

    ave(g, g, FUN = function(z) z[1] == w)    
}

DT[, keepem := tag.long.seq(fyear), by=gvkey]

DT[(keepem==1L), .N] # 149 again
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like a very elegant solution, but I'm getting an error in the second line for `keep` : `The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (172,16). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (172).`  ... Also, what's the `!=1L` doing in `cumsum`?

Comment: @TonyBeans Hm, not sure why you're hitting that error. The `!= 1` is a logical test, TRUE if the gap is not one, FALSE otherwise. These are mapped to 1/0 respectively when `cumsum` is applied to the result.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo when I tried it.  This works perfectly for both versions of `data.table`.  I hadn't even though of `tail` -- very nice. Thank you.  (And now I see what's going on in `cumsum`, thnx).  Even though this solves the ultimate problem, I think I should hold off on accepting it as an answer since my question was a more general issue with understanding `j`.  Nevertheless, greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Tony I've added an alternative function. It works directly on `fyear` instead of creating the intermediate variable `gap`. Still not sure where your function goes wrong, though. Maybe it's because you have `NA` for the first row when you use `shift` (and should instead be using the `fill=` option of that function).

Comment: I don't have any particular need to do this in base R (that was just my original approach when `data.table` 1.9.6 wasn't working, but your `data.table`-fu made this moot).  Interestingly, this updated `tag.long.seq` works fine on my machine as well.  I tried using the `fill= fyear[1L] - 1L` option in my original `find.seq.keep` func, but still get the same result: `nrow(DT.outF) #[1] 141`. So, I still don't understand what's wrong, but thanks again for another (and better) solution!