# not getting the same result from within the "j" parameter of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm calling a function from within the "j" parameter of a data.table, and I'm not getting the same result as I would if I called it directly.  This seems related to [my function called in data.table j not returning expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249586/my-function-called-in-data-table-j-not-returning-expected-results)

```
get.lower.bound <- function (x) {
  rex <-
    regexpr (pattern = "((?<lower>[\\-+\\d*\\.,]*)%\\s*<\\s*)?X(\\s<\\s(?<uppper>[\\-+\\d\\.,]*)%)?",
             text = x,
             perl = TRUE)
  lower_bound <-
    substring(
      text = x,
      first = attr(rex, "capture.start")[2],
      last = attr(rex, "capture.start")[2] + attr(rex, "capture.length")[2] -1
    )
  lower_bound
}

dat <- data.table(
  A = c('1% < X < 2%', '4% < X',      'X < 8%' ),
  B = c('2% < X < 3%', '5% < X < 6%', '8% < X < 9%' ),
  C = c('3% < X < 4%', '6% < X < 7%', 'X < 10%' )
)

get.lower.bound(dat[1,'A'])                   # this returns 1; as I expect
get.lower.bound(dat[2,'A'])                   # this returns 4; as I expect
get.lower.bound(dat[3,'A'])                   # this returns a blank string; as I expect
dat[i = 1, j = .(lb1 = get.lower.bound(A))]   # this returns a data table of just one cell with 1 in it; as I expect
dat[i = 1:3, j = A]                           # this returns a character vector with the original strings in it; as I expect
dat[i = 1:3, j = .(lb1 = c(A))]               # this returns a data table with the original strings in it; as I expect
dat[i = 1:3, j = .(lb1 = get.lower.bound(A))] # this returns "1% <", "4% <", "X < 8"; but I expect a "1", "4" & ""
```

Why isn't the last line giving me what I expect?  What do I need to do to get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is because your function `get.lower.bound` isn't vectorised. It gives the expected output if you group it by each row and then pass the function.

```
library(data.table)
dat[, j = .(lb1 = get.lower.bound(A)),  by = 1:nrow(dat)]

#   nrow lb1
#1:    1   1
#2:    2   4
#3:    3
```